# Activate Python code by a shortcut. Search for a selected element in a database

Tags: python

Is there a way I can activate python code by a shortcut?

The idea is, I highlight (or select) text in Outlook, Web browser, or anywhere else, click something like Ctrl + Shift + D and this would activate a python code to search for this element in my database. Ideally, it would give me a pop-up window with some info on this element and URL link.

The search portion is easy, but have no idea (and couldn't find) how to trigger code in the way I described.

Thanks for you support!

Comment: Try the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) package.

Comment: @L3viathan Just tried this one, but it's a bit glitchy, two times my computer behaved really weird when I tried just to click on something. Is it the same for you?

Comment: I've never used it by myself; never had a use for it.